# \r not working in awk's printf?

Tags: bash, awk, printf

Found this script by googling, it has a progress bar for cp, the problem is that it creates tons of lines, like this:

> 0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   0% [=>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>
>   1% [==>

here is the script's code:

```
#!/bin/bash

   strace -q -ewrite cp --  `printf '%q ' $@` 2>&1 \
      | awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%3d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent;i++)
                  printf "="
               printf ">"
               for (i=percent;i<100;i++)
                  printf " "
               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=$(stat -c '%s' "${1}") count=0
```

One more thing, the line with the ======'s is too long.  Like, when getting up towards the 90's, the ===='s spill out on to the next line.  How could I edit this so it would print 75 
or so lines, since my default terminal is 80 wide.

Edit:  Ok I realized, this will not work if a file has a space in it.  [It just doesn't do anything, and exits right after I type the command]. Any ideas?

Thank you. :)

Comment: note: you might want to check pv(pipe progress and rate viewer)

Answer (score 2):

Take out the `printf " "` before the `printf "]\r":

```
#!/bin/bash

strace -q -ewrite cp --  `printf '%q ' $@` 2>&1 \
  | awk '{
    count += $NF
        if (count % 10 == 0) {
           percent = count / total_size * 100
           printf "%3d%% [", percent
           for (i=0;i<=percent;i++)
              printf "="
           printf ">"
           for (i=percent;i<100;i++)
              printf "]\r"
        }
     }
     END { print "" }' total_size=$(stat -c '%s' "${1}") count=0
```

Also, your terminal window needs to be wide enough to handle all the characters (110 characters or more).

Comment: What would that accomplish, besides erasing the first character in the line, a whole lot of times?  :-)

Comment: @Adam Liss -- good point!  That said, it works on my Linux terminal...okay, I fixed it by simply taking out all of the spaces.

Comment: it "works" because it doesn't go to the next line of the terminal. and it won't work as soon as percent goes high enough

Comment: Ok.. so now, I just need to reduce the amount of ===='s that are required till the meter is at full. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If your percentage never decreases, you don't need the second `for` loop (which clears the remainder of the line by printing spaces).

Any chance those spaces are advancing your cursor to the next line, and the `\r` simply puts the cursor in the 1st column of that new line?

You can test this by ensuring your terminal width is > 100 characters.

*Thanks to Random832 for this:*

To shorten the line:

```
if (count % 10 == 0) {
       percent = count / total_size * 100
       printf "%3d%% [", percent
       # Limit the line length to 40 chars
       width = percent * 40 / 100
       for (i=0;i<=width;i++)
          printf "="
       printf ">]\r"
    }
```

Comment: Ok so I took out the for loop that prints " " and now, it doesn't print extra lines till it gets to the edge of my terminal [till it spills over to the next line].         And now about the "change 100 to 40" that is not working for me. because then it goes to about 30 or 40 percent and then it is done copying.. :\

Comment: make a separate variable for this, and use that for the = loop, while still using percent for the `printf "%3d%%"`.

Comment: Random832, I do not understand.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Matt, my last edit incorporates Random832's suggestion.  Calculate `percent` and print it numerically, but calculate `width` separately and use it to determine the width of the bar of asterisks.